# New pc causing "namespace of type specified in the imports doesn't contain any public member" in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, public, member, import

I just got a new PC (Win 7) with VS 2010 (same version as my old PC).  I got a VB.NET solution from source control that contains two projects.  One of the projects builds fine.  The other project flags every non-MS Imports statement with:

Namespace or type specified in the Imports &1 doesn't contain any public members or cannot be found.  Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member.  Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

The ironic thing is that the working project within the same solution references all the same DLL's.  I've removed and re-added the DLL's so I know they're there, and I can expand them in Object Browser, so I know they contain public methods.

I've ran out of ideas of things to try.  Can someone throw me a bone, plz?

Comment: Does the working project have the same Imports statements?  What if you create a brand new project and add the references and then add the Imports statements.  Does that work?  Are you using file references or project references?

Comment: Could it be that the two projects reference different versions of the assemblies?  Does the new PC perhaps only have one version installed but the old one has several?

Comment: Both projects use the same Imports and the external references point to the same file locations.  The failing project has a reference to the working project that is also not working.  Both projects have the references defined on the References tab under My Project.  A new project within the same solution seems to work fine, but replacing the failing project would be a horrible pain.

Comment: `"working project that is also not working"`  The working project is not working??  Have you tried just deleting the Bin and Obj folders for the projects and cleaning the solution and then a full rebuild?

Comment: The bad project is getting the error referencing the good project within the same solution, as well as external DLLs.  I deleted boths sets oF Bin & Obj folders, did a Clean Solution and a Build Solution.  I still got all the "Type &1 is not defined" plus "Cannot register assembly &2 - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator.  Access to registry key &3 is denied."  Where &2 is the path to the Debug copy of the DLL for the working project.  Does VS have to be ran as admin?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem which I fixed by changing the Project Properties->Compile->Advanced Compile Options->Target Framework value from .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile to .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 7):

I had this happen. For me, the new DLL was targeting Dot Net 4.5, while the project which referenced it was only targeting 4.0.  Switching the new dll to match fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue as this before. In my case the problem was that the dll's were located on a network share drive (which in my system showed as q:) so when I referenced them the file path was q:\folder structure\file.dll. Upon switching machines, my system no longer referenced that share drive as q:\ but by another drive letter, causing my program to error out similarly.

In my case, I was able to correct this issue and prevent it from happening again by changing the way I referenced the dll from the drive letter it was assigned by my local system to the network path (\SERVER NAME\Drive Letter\file path\file.dll).

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. The DLL I was referencing was built in framework 3.5.  The project I was referencing the DLL was being built in 2.0.  I switched the referring project to 3.5 and it built perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with projects which were referencing the same version of the framework. I solved it with the following steps.

1. Remove reference to DLL
2. Clean and ReBuild DLL
3. Clean and ReBuild Project
4. ReAdd Reference.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in a Visual Studio 2019 VB project with System.Data.SqlClient . Since the Import of System.Data.SqlClient was failing, all of my Sql classes used in declarations on the page -- SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader -- were undefined.

To fix it, I just had to use a full reference to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection when declaring my very first variable for one of those classes on the page:

```
Using conn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
```

By changing just that first declaration on the page, it fixed the compilation error on the Imports line and all subsequent declarations on the page. (Even stranger, after building the project once like that, I was able to revert the declaration back to just referencing SqlConnection, and the Import worked and the page is compiling fine. So it may have been a temporary issue unrelated to my temporary fix)

Answer (score 0):

I had already fixed this problem once I got to the point of googling this, and all I had to do was delete and re-add the reference in the solution explorer