# Namespace or type specified in the project-level Imports 'System.Threading.Tasks' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to resolve this below warning message. Project is not referring the System.Threading anywhere but still I get this below error message. Only difference is that, The Project's solution has around 50 plus projects, some are written in C# and some are in VB. few project targets 4.5 framework and few targets 3.0 framework.

> Namespace or type specified in the project-level Imports
>   'System.Threading.Tasks' doesn't contain any public member or cannot
>   be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains
>   at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name
>   doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New pc causing “namespace of type specified in the imports doesn't contain any public member” in VB.NE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322678/new-pc-causing-namespace-of-type-specified-in-the-imports-doesnt-contain-any-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your 3.0 VB projects is importing `System.Threading.Tasks` in a project setting, The namespace `System.Threading.Tasks` was not introduced till .NET 4.0.

Find the place that has it incorrectly added and remove it.

Comment: I was able to find the reference to _System.Threading.Tasks_ in some of the 3.0 VB projects *.vbproj files and removed them. All such warnings disappeared.